# Javascript calculating a formula

Tags: javascript, math

I am working on changing a percentage value of a panel based on the screen size of a device.
I need to work out the following formula.

Starting at screen width 320 and ending at screen width 1200.

```
If screenWidth < 320 percentageWidth = 98
If screenWidth > 1200 percentageWidth = 65
```

From the above I can work out manually that:
If screenWidth = 760 percentageWidth = 82.

What is the formula I need so I can change percentageWidth on a screen width change?

Comment: How on Earth did you "work out manually" that?

Comment: I worked out that 760 is the middle value between 320 & 1200 and 82 is the middle value between 98 & 65.

Answer (score 4):

That's just simple math:

You start with the minimum of 65 and add a relative amount depending on the screen width:

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/89gP4/)</kbd>

```
function getPercentageWidth(screenWidth) {
   return 65 + 33 * (Math.min(Math.max(screenWidth, 320), 1200) - 320) / 880;
}

getPercentageWidth(0) // 65
getPercentageWidth(320) // 65
getPercentageWidth(1200) // 98
getPercentageWidth(2400) // 98
getPercentageWidth(760) // 81.5
```

Inverse version <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/89gP4/1)</kbd>

This version starts with 98 and subtracts the relative amount:

```
function getPercentageWidth(screenWidth) {
   return 98 - 33 * (Math.min(Math.max(screenWidth, 320), 1200) - 320) / 880;
}

getPercentageWidth(0) // 98
getPercentageWidth(320) // 98
getPercentageWidth(1200) // 65
getPercentageWidth(2400) // 65
getPercentageWidth(760) // 81.5
```

The other answers use if/else but you can also use Math.min and Math.max:

```
Math.max(screenWidth, 320) // Will always return 320 or more
Math.min(screenWidth, 1200) // Will always return 1200 or less
```

So the result of `(Math.min(Math.max(screenWidth, 320), 1200) - 320) / 880` will always be between 0 and 1.

Comment: I like the 'that's simple math' The last time I did simple math was probably at the age of 12 (40 years ago). The above works but in reverse of what I needed. ie getPercentageWidth(32) needs to = 98. Thanks

Comment: Hey SteveW - I have just added an inverse version

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't explicitly say so, it appears that you're predicting a linear correlation between `screenWidth` and `percentageWidth`. If so, here's an example of code that you can put into a function for the result:

```
minScreenWidth = 320;
maxScreenWidth = 1200;
diffScreenWidth = maxScreenWidth - minScreenWidth;

maxPercentageWidth = 98;    // At screenWidth = 320
minPercentageWidth = 65;    // At screenWidth = 1200
diffPercentageWidth = maxPercentageWidth - minPercentageWidth;

screenWidth = 760;    // Change this as needed.
ratioScreenWidth = (screenWidth - minScreenWidth) / diffScreenWidth;

percentageWidth = maxPercentageWidth - (ratioScreenWidth * diffPercentageWidth);

// Since your example gave 82 as the desired result instead of 81.5,
// I infer that you want the answer rounded.
resultPercentageWidth = Math.round(percentageWidth);
```

@jantimon posted his answer first, with a very elegant one-line function (which I have upvoted). I kept working on this answer in the meantime because I had taken a different approach of breaking down the steps in the hope that it will help you analyze other math functions that you need to apply to JavaScript.

I see that you are a new user. Welcome. And when you return to view the answers, please remember to mark one of them as correct (whichever was most useful to you), and to upvote any that were useful to you, if your reputation points allow it.

Also, when you post questions in the future, please be aware that you're also expected to show examples of your own attempts and the results of those attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
function doCalc(sw) {
  var pw;

  if (sw < 320) {
    pw = 98;
  } else if (sw > 1200) {
    pw = 65;
  } else {
 // pw = 98 - (98 - 65) * (sw - 320) / (1200 - 320);
    pw = 98 - 33 * (sw - 320) / 880;
  }
  return Math.round(pw);
}
```

or if you like one liners:

```
function doCalc(sw) {
  return Math.round(sw<320? 98 : sw>1200? 65 : 98 - 33*(sw-320)/880);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer delivers opposite results, the second the wrong values for screenWidth < 320 and screenWidth > 1200. This one is hopefully correct and maybe a little more readable:

```
var calculatePercentageWidth = function(screenWidth) {

    var MAX_SCREEN = {percentage: 65, width: 1200};
    var MIN_SCREEN = {percentage: 98, width: 320};

    if (screenWidth < MIN_SCREEN.width) {
        return MIN_SCREEN.percentage;
    } else if (screenWidth > MAX_SCREEN.width) {
        return MAX_SCREEN.percentage;
    } else {
        var coefficient = (MIN_SCREEN.percentage - MAX_SCREEN.percentage) / (MAX_SCREEN.width - MIN_SCREEN.width);
        return Math.round(MAX_SCREEN.percentage + (screenWidth - MIN_SCREEN.width) * coefficient);
    }
}
```

If the values for the maximum and minimum width or percentage change, you only need to change the values in the constants at the top of the function.

To calculate the percentageWidth for screenWidth = 760, write:

```
calculatePercentageWidth(760);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBCLw/)

### Corrected version:

```
var calculatePercentageWidth = function(screenWidth) {

    var MAX_SCREEN = {percentage: 65, width: 1200};
    var MIN_SCREEN = {percentage: 98, width: 320};

    if (screenWidth < MIN_SCREEN.width) {
        return MIN_SCREEN.percentage;
    } else if (screenWidth > MAX_SCREEN.width) {
        return MAX_SCREEN.percentage;
    } else {
        var coefficient = (MIN_SCREEN.percentage - MAX_SCREEN.percentage) / (MAX_SCREEN.width - MIN_SCREEN.width);
        return Math.round(MIN_SCREEN.percentage - (screenWidth - MIN_SCREEN.width) * coefficient);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBCLw/1/)

Comment: Thanks. This one is the wrong way round. If the screenWidth = 1200 & need the percentage to be 65. If the screenWidth = 320 I need the percentage to be 98.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).  For two points, (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) there exists a straight line.  Linear interpolation takes any value x between x0 and x1 and calculates the y value that falls on that line.  The general case is computed as:

```
y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0)
```

For your case, the two points are (320, 98) and (1200, 65).  This results in the equation:

```
y = 98 - 33 * (x - 320) / 880
```

To validate your calculation, set x = 760:

```
y = 98 - 33 * (760 - 320) / 880
  = 98 - 33 * 440 / 880
  = 98 - 33 / 2
  = 98 - 16.5
  = 81.5
```